# Laravel show multi-select saved values in edit view

Tags: php, laravel, enums, laravel-5.3

I have a `Project` model which has a multi-select field called `project_type`. I am using [Select2](https://select2.github.io/) for the field.

I've set up an enum in `config/enum.php` like this:

```
<?php

return [
    'project_types' => [
        '0' => 'WordPress Brochure Website',
        '1' => 'WordPress WooCommerce Website',
        '2' => 'Drupal Website',
        '3' => 'SEO',
        '4' => 'Branding',
        '5' => 'Bespoke Web App'
    ]
];

?>
```

In my `create` view I have a form with the field as such:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'projects')) }}

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('Project Type') !!}
            {!! Form::select('project_type[]', Config::get('enums.project_types'), null, ['multiple'=>'multiple']); !!}
        </div>

{{ Form::submit('Create Project', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

Then in my controller when I save the multi-select field values I convert the array into a string to store into the DB:

```
public function store(ProjectRequest $request)
    {
        $project_type = $request->input('project_type');
        $project_type = implode(',', $project_type);
        $input = $request->except('project_type');
        $input['project_type'] = $project_type;
        Project::create($input);
        return redirect()->route('projects')->with('message', 'Rate created.');
    }
```

This will store the multi-select field in a format like this `0,1,3`.
This saves fine however now when I want to edit the project I need to pull out the values from the db and populate the multi-select field, this is where I'm struggling, here is what I have in my `edit` view.

```
   {{ Form::model($project, array('route' => array('projects.update', $project->id), 'method' => 'PUT')) }}

                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('Project Type') !!}
                    {!! Form::select('project_type[]', Config::get('enums.project_types'), 1, ['multiple'=>'multiple']); !!}
                </div>

                {{ Form::submit('Update Project', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

**At the moment you can see I've hard coded the default value for the multi-select field to `1` but is there a way I can set the default value of the multi-select field to what is stored in the db?**

Comment: I'm not 100% on this, but have you tried converting what you have in your database back to an array using `explode(',', $values)` and putting the result where you have hard-coded `1`?

Comment: I did exactly that as you posted the comment :) See answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically exactly what @Jonathon said in the comments, I need to turn my imploded string back into an array and pass that to the default value parameter:

```
<?php
    // explode the saved data back into an array                    
    $project_type = explode(',', $project->project_type);
?>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('Project Type') !!}
        {!! Form::select('project_type[]', Config::get('enums.project_types'), $project_type, ['multiple'=>'multiple']); !!}
    </div>
```

Comment: You can call explode function in 'Form::select()'